# add width attribute to img in a string

Tags: javascript

lets say i have string something like

```
x = '<div class="sample">
     <img src="http://www.example.com/i/java.png"> 
 </div>
 <div class="sample_another">
     <img src="/i/somedir/python.png"> 
</div>'
```

i have 2 functions with me

getheight() => returns img height and 
getwidth() => returns img width

I want to add the width and the height attribute to the img tags whose value i can get it from those functions. i couldnt find regex for this so i was thinking more of a general approach.

This is what i came up with so far

```
var string ="<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>";

var elem= document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = string;

var images = elem.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(img in images){
   ...
}
```

but after i dont know how to proceed as this is converted from dom elements to string. and i still have to append height and width.

my final string should be something like this

```
x = '<div class="sample">
         <img src="http://www.example.com/i/java.png" height="200px" width="100px"> 
     </div>
     <div class="sample_another">
         <img src="/i/somedir/python.png" width="150px" height="150px"> 
    </div>'
```

can anyone help me achieve this please. Thanks

Comment: Do not use regex for parsing HTML! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Our_Benefactors _"This is what i came up with so far..."_ I don't see any regular expressions in the script

Comment: Your final string looks exactly like the original string? Also, why get the height and width of an image, just to add those in attributes?

Comment: @Our_Benefactors yes thats why i made it into html and tried to do it but i dont know how to proced forward

Comment: @adeneo. so sorry . edited now :)

Comment: @Andreas i couldnt find anything decent with rgex. so i came up with this html dom solution

Comment: If you create the images with `new Image` adding attributes is just `setAttribute('height', something)`

Comment: @adeneo after that i also want to see the changes in string x. thats where i am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `height` property to set the value of the height attribute of an image. And `width` to set width.

Use for loop as shown below if you have multiple `img` tags in your string. If not you can simply use `images[0]` without for loop.

EDIT : If you want to change the string itself, just reassign the string as shown below

```js
var string ="<img alt='' src='http://api.com/images/UID' /><br/>Some plain text<br/><a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>";

var elem= document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = string;

var images = elem.getElementsByTagName("img");

for(i=0; i<images.length; i++){
   images[i].width = "150";
   images[i].height = "250";
}

string = elem.innerHTML;  // reassign the 'string' with new value
console.log(string);
```

Comment: In addition to this i also want to plug the height and width attributes to the img tag inside the main string x.

Comment: @Pujan You mean like this ?